# Illustrator coloring question

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

This might sound like a really stupid question but is there a way to color the area i marked with red color? I tried enclosing the mouth area with the red line using pen tool but obviously it's not working. Is it possible or do i need to trace the whole mouth area?

Comment: Hi cheesetrix, welcome to GD.SE! What do you mean creating a new object with the pen tool doesn't work, what doesn't work about doing that? Is your object set to stroke instead of fill?

Comment: The pen tools works it is not about that. I have traced my alligator as you can see and coloured it. But i can't fill inside mouth with color. I want to find out is it possible colour it or do i have to trace a countour of it.

Comment: Its better for you to think of illustrator as cutting paper than drawing or painting. Use shspe builder.

Answer (score 7):

Draw a closed shape that will fill the space you want in the gator's mouth. Set the Fill to the red color you want and then choose Object> Arrange> Send To Back which moves it under the gator shape in the Layers Panel.

EDIT- Additional information-
It seems you were trying to "paint in" the red color for inside the gator's mouth. With Vector artwork, *for the most part*, you need to think not in terms of painting or coloring areas but more in terms of stacking shapes- more similar to cutting out pieces of colored paper and then stacking them together.

[image]